SwiftUI TabItem not showing
I have a homepageView which contains a MainView, and I can see the space for the bottom tabs but not the bottom tab item unfortunately.
struct HomepageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TopBar()
            MainView()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
    }
}
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tabs = .shop
    @StateObject private var categoriesListViewModel = CategoriesListViewModel(categories: SampleCategories().categoriesList)

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            VStack {
                ShopView(model: categoriesListViewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Shop")
                    }
                    .tag(Tabs.shop)
            }
        }
    }
}

I added the VStack within TabView because without it, I don't see the ShopView at all.
Does anyone know why I'm unable to see the text "Shop" (my tab item)?

Put the tab item code on the vstack

try removing the VStack in your TabView, works for me.
